# Applet + JNLP CNF error under Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, applet, jnlp

Trying to deploy a java applet with JNLP launcher.

Works only under Mozzila Firefox. Under chrome I am getting CassNotFoundException...

### JNLP

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href=""> 
<security> 
     <all-permissions /> 
</security> 
<information> 
    <title>VCODE Printer Applet</title> 
    <vendor>Infosolo LTDA</vendor> 
</information> 
<resources> 
     <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" /> 
    <jar href="/vcode/vcodeprint-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true" /> 
</resources> 
<applet-desc 
    name="VCODE Printer Applet" 
    main-class="HelloWorld" 
    width="300" 
    height="300"> 
        <param name="qr" value="QTP011829223124JCQS30OQ2963531142 121722263541"/> 
</applet-desc> 
<update check="background"/>
```

### XHTML

```xhtml
<applet code = 'HelloWorld' 
    jnlp_href = '../vcodePrinter.jnlp?id=#{consultaPlacaBean.placaConsultada.id}'
    width = '300'
    height = '300' />
```

This HelloWorld applet has almost same code from HelloWorld applet tutorial from oracle.

### Full stack trace

```
etwork: Entrada de cache não encontrada [url: http://localhost:8080/vcode/qr/HelloWorld.class, versão: null]
network: Conectando http://localhost:8080/vcode/qr/HelloWorld.class ao proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://localhost:8080/ ao proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://localhost:8080/vcode/qr/HelloWorld.class ao cookie "JSESSIONID=9Yg2H+cWMuAgiC1oThoBG2on.undefined"
network: Entrada de cache não encontrada [url: http://localhost:8080/vcode/qr/HelloWorld.class, versão: null]
network: Conectando http://localhost:8080/vcode/qr/HelloWorld.class ao proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://localhost:8080/vcode/qr/HelloWorld.class ao cookie "JSESSIONID=9Yg2H+cWMuAgiC1oThoBG2on.undefined"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
basic: carga: classe HelloWorld não encontrada.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
basic: Listener de progresso removido: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1ff27ff5
security: Redefinir armazenamento de certificados da sessão negada
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
```

---

Is this a security issue? Chrome do not let self signed applets to run? Under Firefox everything works OK.

PS: Linux Fedora 19, sun java JDK 1.7
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Plugin version: Java(TM) Web Start 10.45.2.18-fcs (Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.45.2 for Mozilla browsers)

It appears that chrome do not understand `jnlp_href` property...

Comment: Tried to especify the JAR but the applet was unable to read the parameters from the JNLP. Chorme do not support JNLP lauchers?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 0):

Since `<applet />` old html tag is deprecated, tried to run the applet with tag `<embed />`.

The code look like this:

```
        <embed type='application/x-java-applet;version=1.7'
               jnlp_href='../vcodePrinter.jnlp?id=#{consultaPlacaBean.placaConsultada.id}'
               width='300'
               height='300' />
```

Before I had to run JaNeLa to correct the jnlp xml settings (thanks to Andrew Thompson)!